# How to SELECT from a temp table name, passed to a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have temp table `name?` as an output from a stored procedure and I passed the `name` of created temp table to another stored procedure as an input parameter.

I want to SELECT Guid from `@CalculationGuidTempTableName VARCHAR` then insert into `@CalcsGuids`.

Here is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ret_Reports_ProxyVoucherAccounting]
    (@CalculationGuidTempTableName VARCHAR(32))
AS
    DECLARE @CalcsGuids TABLE ([Guid] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY)

    --INSERT INTO @CalcsGuids (SELECT * FROM  + @CalculationGuidTempTableName)
    --DROP TABLE  @CalculationGuidTempTableName
    WITH temp AS
    (
        SELECT
            reference.DetailPureTitle,
            reference.DetailCaption,
            reference.Nature,
            reference.Summarize
        FROM 
            @CalcsGuids calcs 
        INNER JOIN
            ret_vwPayrollCalculationBackPayForReport details ON details.CalculationGuid = calcs.[Guid] 
        LEFT JOIN 
            ret_PaymentAllocation payment ON payment.Guid = Details.ItemGuid 
        INNER JOIN 
            ret_vwFactorReferences reference ON reference.ItemGuid = Details.ItemGuid 
        INNER JOIN 
            ret_PayrollCalculationCommands command ON command.[Guid] =  details.CalculationCommandGuid
        WHERE
            command.Approved = 1 AND command.Deleted = 0
        GROUP BY
            reference.DetailPureTitle,
            reference.DetailCaption,
            reference.Nature,
            reference.Summarize
    )
    SELECT 
        * 
    FROM
        temp 
    WHERE 
        PayAmount <> 0 OR
        DeductionAmount <> 0 OR
        EmployerAmount <> 0 
    ORDER BY 
        Nature
```

Comment: Use dynamic SQL.

Comment: @ZoharPeled nice hint, I tried and it worked.

Comment: INSERT INTO @CalcsGuids EXEC ('SELECT * FROM ' + @CalculationGuidTempTableName);

Comment: Glad to help :-) Please consider either posting an answer to the question and accepting it when the system lets you, or delete the question. I'm sure if we searched we could find duplicates all over SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
  INSERT INTO @CalcsGuids EXEC ('SELECT * FROM ' + @CalculationGuidTempTableName);
```